# Eliminar ejes Matplotlib imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib

quería saber si se puede eliminar esos números que me indican los píxeles al representar una imagen. Pongo el siguiente ejemplo [image: Representación de un mosaico de imágenes]

Esos números resultan muy molestos a la hora de representar en formato matricial, sobre todo si es 2x2. Tengo que utilizar esta librería para representar imágenes, pero no veo que parámetro es el que debo modificar para conseguirlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes evitar simplemente que se muestren los ejes con `matplotlib.pyplot.axis('off')`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.image import imread

img = imread('ruta/a/imagen')
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

o `matplotlib.axes.Axes.axis('off')` si se usa una figura explícitamente creada o subplots como en tu caso:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.image import imread


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
img = imread('pan.png')
ax.imshow(img)
ax.axis("off")
plt.show()
```